# Airflow DAG does not run on schedule, "next run" is 4 hours ago

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have an Airflow DAG (Airflow 2.6) where the code looks like this:

```
DAG(dag_id="my_dag",
         start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 5, 1, tz="America/Chicago"),
         schedule_interval="0 4 * * *", # Every day at 4AM Central
         catchup=False) as dag:
```

Note that this is a timezone-aware DAG for the America/Chicago timezone: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags

We turned this DAG on yesterday evening and it immediately began running for its 2023-05-22 run, which we allowed to happen:
[image: 2023-05-22 run]

Then we expect at 4AM today, 2023-05-23 it would run, but it never did.

[image: run in the past]

You can see the data interval ended at 4am this morning but the DAG never triggered. it even says the next run is 5 hours ago. This plainly seems like a bug to me, but I was hoping for a second opinion, perhaps I don't understand scheduling in Airflow. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Why did it not run at 4am?

Thank you!

EDIT: At exactly 9AM CDT(so 14:00 UTC) the DAG kicked off and ran. This seems even more confusing to me: my schedule is 0 4 * * * in the America/Chicago timezone. I don't understand how this translates to 9AM America/Chicago or 2PM UTC.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a GitHub issue for this for Airflow: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/31487. Turns out this is a bug when using MSSQL as your backing DB server. Airflow only has experimental support for MSSQL and they are considering removing it entirely since there's no one with the time to maintain it and develop the support. https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/31487#issuecomment-1561974532.

There's a hacky fix if you're using MSSQL as your backing DB and you're experiencing this bug: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/21171#issuecomment-1363016567 You need to change two lines of code in the Airflow package in your Python environment as mentioned in this comment.

We decided that since we are still in the proof-of-concept phase and that since MSSQL support will potentially be pulled in future Airflow releases, we are going to switch to Postgresql which has the most usage and support from the Airflow community.